# Why is there a difference in Java code compilation: mvn verify vs mvn compile

Tags: java, maven

Short version:
Does `mvn compile` and `mvn verify` compile the code in the same way?

Problem:

I have a multimodule project. And using Maven v3.6.

POM looks like this:

```
    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>plugins</module>
    </modules>
```

A class in server module got modified where a new method got added.
A class in plugins module is calling that method.

Build is successful with following maven commands:

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn -DskipTests verify
```

but compilation of `plugin` module fails when we run:

```
mvn clean
mvn -DskipTests verify
```

with an error that complains about not finding new method in `server` module class:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

So, why is this difference in behaviour. As per [this documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#usual-command-line-calls) `verify` should first call `compile`. So effectively the same thing as first version of commands.

**Notes:**

- Also fails `mvn -DskipTests compile verify`
- Successfully builds : `mvn -DskipTests install`

I do not want to resort to `mvn install` as advice against over [here](https://andresalmiray.com/maven-verify-or-clean-install/)

Regards

Comment: This should not be the case. `mvn verify` should work.

Comment: What version of Maven, and are plugin versions reasonably current?

Comment: Edited question to mention maven version